# How to access an array from the main method?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static int arraylistExample() {
    int length [] = new int [10];

    length[0] = 2;
    length[1] = 3;
    length[5] = 8;  

    return length [1];
}
```

I have written in the main method this: 
System.out.println(length[5]);

Hence, my code looks like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Javanotes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(length[5]);
    }

    public static int arraylistExample() {
        int length [] = new int [10];

        length[0] = 2;
        length[1] = 3;
        length[5] = 8;  

        return length [1];
    }
}
```

and I get a "0" what should I do?

Comment: This does not compile as is

Comment: `and I get a "0"` that is strange since this code shouldn't compile. `int length []` is *local* variable of `arraylistExample` method so you can't access that *variable* from different places.

Comment: So, what do you recommend me doing?

Comment: Move the `length` to the scope which `main` can see. i.e. move it up two lines.

Comment: BTW unless you call `arraylistExample()` it won't do anything.

Comment: It doesnt recognise "length"

Comment: Gentle reminder, this is a Q&A site, not a free tutor site. I recommend reading through a tutorial like [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/) to learn the basics of the language. Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask a good question; remember to research first but thank you for including your code in a code block.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) The array is defined in the method scope of `arraylistExample`(). It is not visible from `main()`.

2) The array will be empty if you never call the method.

You could change it in this way :

```
public class Javanotes {

    static int length [];

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        System.out.println(arraylistExample()); // print 3
        System.out.println(length[5]); // print 8
    }

    public static int arraylistExample() {
        length = new int [10]; // init the static field

        length[0] = 2;
        length[1] = 3;
        length[5] = 8;  

        return length [1];
    }
}
```

But note that using `static` everywhere is generally not the right thing.
You do that for utility classes.

Comment: The second println gives me 0

Comment: @Northern Front Swain This should not

Answer (score -1):

You should declare the function before calling it.
your function **arraylistexample** is not seen by the main class

Comment: What? No. The order you define the methods in has no bearing on this.